# Cout and Cin in Linux - can't see the console

Tags: c++, linux, console, cout

I just moved from Windows to Linux and I'm try to create a simple application that opens a console, displays a message and wait for key press to close. I have created it on Windows and it works, then I just moved the files to Linux. Didn't make any change, just compiled it with g++ and I get no errors. The problem is that on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) I can't see the console and some message asking me to press any key before closing. My code is as simple as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    cout << "Writing file...\n";

        FILE *myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
        fwrite("test", sizeof(char), 4, myfile);
        fclose(myfile);

    cout << "Press any key to exit...\n";
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

On Windows, when I start the executable, the console windows will show me the messages and close when pressing any key. On Linux, when I execute the program I don't get anything. It does create the testfile.txt file and insert the text, so *cstdio* related functions does work, but I can't see any console with those messages and I don't understand why. Maybe I don't know how to open a simple executable on Linux. What I want is to double click on it and see a console with two simple messages. What do you thin I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Also, I use g++ to compile the cpp file: `g++ -Wall -s -O2 test.cpp -o test`

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't even compile. But if it did, you would have an executable called `test`, which you can execute from a console by typing `./test` from the directory where it is located.

Comment: It sounds like you're running it from a desktop gui - there's more than one of those used on Linux, you probably need to specify which one (or at least the distro you're using).

Comment: Sorry, I typed the code letter by letter, I might have inserted some wrong character. The code compiles, that's not the problem. As I said, the fwrite works, it creates a text file. What I can't see is a console displaying me the messages. I don't want to use the terminal for this, I just want to click on it and open the console with the messages on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows the "natural" form of an application is a GUI application. When you run a console application the system creates a window to run a console and runs the application in that window. That is done by Windows, it is not an inherent property of C++ and is not implied by the code you wrote.

C++ doesn't do this automatically and UNIX-like systems don't do this for you.

On UNIX-like systems the "natural" type of application is (arguably) a console application and you would typically run them *from* a console or terminal.

When you run your program the output goes to the terminal where your X11 session is running, but you don't see it because the X11 session is controlling your display.

So to get the behaviour you want, first open a terminal, then run the program.

To make the program run in a terminal, try running something like `xterm -e ./test`

To make that automatic you could kluge it with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc > 1 && std::string(argv[1]) == "-xterm")
  {
    if (::execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "-e", argv[0], (char*)NULL))
    {
      std::perror("execl");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Writing file...\n";

  FILE* myfile = std::fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
  std::fwrite("test", sizeof(char), 4, myfile);
  std::fclose(myfile);

  std::cout << "Press any key to exit...\n";
  std::cin.get();
}
```

Now if you run the program with the argument `-xterm` it will run in an xterm.

N.B. I fixed your non-portable code to use `std::` qualification on the names from `<cstdio>`

Comment: Nice `exec` example. Unfortunately I cannot up-vote a second time.

Answer (score 2):

Windows opens a console, since that's the only way that stdio will work on it. Linux doesn't since stdio can function without it (with output going to the X session error log, `~/.xsession-errors` by default). If you want to have stdio accessible to the user then you need to open a terminal and shell first and run the executable in there.

Comment: I could create a shell script to open the executable, then, I mean, to make this a click and open application

Comment: That won't help. The same thing will happen. Create a .desktop file instead that runs it in a terminal.

Comment: I think you're right. So, there's no way to open the terminal from the executable, then, show the messages. If I want output to the screen I first must open the terminal, then execute the program from it. Suppose this is the way things work on Linux.

Comment: @ali you could play with `fork` and `exec` to "spawn" a terminal from your program, then do the rest.

Comment: @juanchopanza, no need to `fork`, just `exec` to replace the current process with an xterm running the same binary

Comment: @juanchopanza, I've updated my answer with an example of doing so

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told your desktop environment to run the program in a terminal window. Your program also doesn't tell, it just writes to its standard output.

To see the standard output of the program, the best is to open a console, and type the name of the compiled program to run it. The standard output of the program will be displayed in the same window.

Answer (score 1):

instead

```
cin.ignore();
```

do a

```
cin.get();
```

in the directory you did the compilation, start the program in a terminal window with:

```
./test
```

it then writes "Writing file..." and "Press any key to exit..." on the standard output and you are required to press any key to terminate the app.

Comment: aerhm... why the downvote? I did the replace because that way the process stops and so he can actually see what is going on AND has to press any key to continue the process