# Clearing the cout buffer (c++)

Tags: c++, cout, flush, ostream

Hello I'm writing a short program to implement a shell and I'm running into an unusual problem. For some reason I can't clear to the std::cout buffer. The program wont print out messages. I understand a simple solution is to switch to std::cerr, but is there a way to get messages to print with cout? 
Things I've tryed:

1. `std::cout.flush()`
2. Inserting `std::endl` after anything is written to standard out.
3. Inserting an `std::flush` into the output stream
4. `std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);` which was something I found that      should unbuffer output.

Any help is much appreciated here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    //Tryed this to unbuffer cout, no luck.
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);

    std::string input;

    //Print out shell prompt and read in input from keyboard.
    std::cout << "myshell> ";   
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    //**********************************************************************
    //Step 1) Read in string and parse into tokens.
    //**********************************************************************

    char * buf = new char[input.length() + 1];
    strcpy(buf, input.c_str());

    int index = 0;
    char * command[256]; 

    command[index] = std::strtok(buf, " ");    //Get first token.
    std::cout << command[index] << std::endl;

    while (command[index] != NULL)
    {
        ++index;
        command[index] = std::strtok(NULL," ");    //Get remaining tokens.
        std::cout << command[index] << std::endl;
    }   

    std::cout.flush(); //No luck here either

    //HERE IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS.
    std::cout << index << " items were added to the command array" << std::endl;

    delete[] buf;

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: It appears you have tried everything listed _[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096103/clearing-the-cout-buffer-c)_.  Are you certain your posted examples match your actual code?  What environment (OS, Compiler) are you using?

Comment: This _[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13809766/645128)_ might help.  By the way, `cout` is purely C++.  I removed the C tag from your post.

Comment: I'm coding in a linux environment with Geany. I'll take a look through the link. The compiler options I'm using are:
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -c "%f"

Build Options:
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -o "%e" "%f"

Comment: I got a segmentation fault 11 when implementing this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending `NULL` to `cout` on the last iteration of the `while` loop, which leads to UB, and in your case is jamming `cout`. Check for `NULL` before you send anything to `cout` and you're fine:

```
if (command[index] != NULL) {
    std::cout << command[index] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to know what happened to your streams, remember that they can carry status information ([the `iostate`, which I recommend you read about](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)). The following code could have helped track your error:

```
 try {
      std::cout.exceptions(std::cout.failbit);          
 } catch(const std::ios_base::failure& e) {
      std::cerr << "stream error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      std::cout.clear();
 }

 // continue working with cout, because std::cout.clear() removed
 // failbit
```

Or, even simpler:

```
if(not std::cout) {
    // address your error (if it is recoverable)
 }
```

This is how your code would have looked like:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    //Tryed this to unbuffer cout, no luck.
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);

    std::string input;

    //Print out shell prompt and read in input from keyboard.
    std::cout << "myshell> ";   
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    //**********************************************************************
    //Step 1) Read in string and parse into tokens.
    //**********************************************************************

    char * buf = new char[input.length() + 1];
    strcpy(buf, input.c_str());

    int index = 0;
    char * command[256]; 

    command[index] = std::strtok(buf, " ");    //Get first token.
    std::cout << command[index] << std::endl;

    while (command[index] != NULL)
    {
        ++index;
        command[index] = std::strtok(NULL," ");    //Get remaining tokens.
        std::cout << command[index] << std::endl;
    }

    // I added from here...
    if(not std::cout) {
      std::cerr << "cout is messed up... fixing it..." << std::endl;
      std::cout.clear();
    }
    // ... to here.

    std::cout.flush(); //No luck here either

    //HERE IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS.
    std::cout << index << " items were added to the command array" << std::endl;

    delete[] buf;

    return 0;   
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./a.out
myshell> 1 2 3
1
2
3
cout is messed up... fixing it...
3 items were added to the command array
```